# Is it possible to change ER diagram style in MySQL Workbench? How?

Tags: mysql-workbench, database-diagrams

I am really new to database visualization. I am creating the ER diagram of my databases. I am using MySQL Workbench 6.3 (community version). I am creating the diagram using the default style. The style looks like this:
[image]

Is it possible to change the style to be like the image below?
[image]

If yes, How can i do this?
or if you have another database designer that can create diagram like the second style, it would help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can change the look of the diagrams a bit, evn though not exactly as shown in your sshot. Under the model menu there are 2 submenus for object and relationship notations:

[image]

The result looks then like this:

[image]